# Cannot find any information on 9-digit decimal TOTP key

Tags: python, base64, totp, base32

Long story short, I'm trying to create a front-end for a 2FA app in Python and I encountered something strange.

Typical TOTP keys are base-32 numbers with 16 or 32 digits, but one of the accounts I was testing instead has a *9-digit decimal* key (for example `091827364`).
On an authenticator app, this behaves just like any other 2FA code, but none of the libraries I've seen in Python support it - they simply use the `base64.b32decode()` function to extract the bytes from the key - but base-32 does not include 1, 8 & 9 which are present in my key, and trying to use it throws an error.

I've thought this integer (at least I assume that's how it's treated) simply gets converted to base-32 before being passed into the hashing program, but even after some trial-and-error I couldn't replicate the 2FA codes I got on my phone app.
There must be some sort of conversion algorithm I'm not aware of. Is there a specific name for this 9-digit key? I've tried searching for different types of TOTP keys, but the only things that ever came up were useless "TOTP vs HOTP" tech blogs...

Comment: https://totp.danhersam.com, for example. It just adds more digits from above.

Answer (score 0):

Select "Use another authenticator" so that it uses a generic protocol to generate the code.